# Function pointer ambiguity with templated parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass an overloaded function pointer to template function as a parameter.

```
float Function1(float par1)
{
 return 0;  
}

float Function1(float par1, float par2)
{
 return 0;  
}

template<typename R, typename A1>
void Bind(R(*func)(A1))
{
   std::cout << "Correct one called\n";
}

template<typename R, typename A1, typename A2>
void Bind(R(*func)(A1, A2))
{
   std::cout << "False one called\n";
}

int main()
{
 Bind<float, float>(&Function1);
}
```

Even tho i call the function with 2 float parameters explicity, compiler can't seem to resolve the correct call. 
Compiler shows an 'ambiguous function call' error.

I have created a small sample here:
[http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY$195](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY%24195)

What's the cause of this error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ambiguity comes when you try to take `Function1`'s address. The compiler sees 2 overloads and it can't know which one you're referring to. You need to explicitly indicate which one you want:

```
Bind(
    static_cast<float(*)(float, float)>(&Function1)
);
```

You're indicating template arguments explicitly on the call to `Bind`, but that's too late, the ambiguity was found before that point.

Comment: is the <float, float> on the Bind call still needed then, since the ambiguity lies elsewhere?

Comment: I can omit the <float, float> safely at this point i assume?
Bind(
    static_cast<float(*)(float, float)>(&Function1)
);

Comment: Sure, the template arguments will be deduced.

Comment: "the problem is that the ambiguity comes before the instantiation of Bind. &Function is ambiguous" is a bit misleading. [Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3VzfRh$2). In the situation of the OP this doesn't happen because both `Bind` overloads are candidates (`A2` is being deduced), so taking the address of the overloaded function cannot be disambiguated. *That* is the root of the ambiguity. [Specifying all parameters](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY$226) in the OP's code calls the other overload for instance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to resolve the ambiguity manually, such as with a cast expression.

```
Bind<float, float>( static_cast< float (*)(float par1, float par2)>( &Function1 ));
```

According to the error message, it's not `Function1` that's ambiguous, it's `Bind`.

```
Compilation finished with errors:
source.cpp:31:4: error: call to 'Bind' is ambiguous
Bind<float, float>(&Function1);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

source.cpp:18:6: note: candidate function [with R = float, A1 = float]
void Bind(R(*func)(A1))
^
source.cpp:24:6: note: candidate function [with R = float, A1 = float, A2 = float]
void Bind(R(*func)(A1, A2))
```

The problems is that you specified two arguments, `<float, float>`, but that doesn't exclude the possibility of a *third* argument which is automatically deduced. C++ allows for explicit and implicit arguments to the same function template call!

Another solution is to force it to resolve the template name without considering implicit arguments. This [works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY%24210) too, but it's more hackish:

```
(*&Bind<float, float>)(&Function1); // Taking address first hides arguments from deduction
```

Comment: If the problem were the templates in Bind, then this would work: http://liveworkspace.org/code/U5NJL$0. The problem is taking the address of an overloaded function. How can the compiler know which of the overloads you're referring to?

Comment: @mfontanini It can resolve an overload by the type of the function pointer parameter. You just introduced more ambiguity by removing the explicit arguments. See my hackish solution for something that does work with no casts.